# Fanatic Badge is not showing right away in profile under "Badges" right after receiving it

Tags: support, stack-overflow, badges, badge-progress, activity-badges

After 100 days of consistency I've attained the first gold badge "Fanatic". Now the badge is disappeared there.

[image]

Also this my [Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13207158/abishethvarman-v). I don't know what it happened and what to do to recover it back.

Comment: You [have earned](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/fanatic?userid=13207158) the badge. It's probably not showing up as your latest badge in your profile summary due to caching.

Comment: @JohnOmielan This isn't a duplicate of that, as in this case the user *has earned* the badge, while in that case, the badge hadn't yet been awarded. This case is different because their "Newest" badge in their profile hasn't updated yet, even though it should have at the time it was awarded.

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog Thank you for your feedback. I may have misread the question. If the OP is stating the badge had appeared in their user profile, but it is not showing now (as indicated in the screen shot), I agree my proposed duplicate question of [100 consecutive days, but no "Fanatic" badge?](/q/75171/562482) doesn't seem to fit very well. As such, I've removed that duplicate close vote and deleted the associated comment.

Comment: @Sonic is correct, it's cached for 30 minutes as the dupe answer says.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and support. The badge is displaying now